# Reversing author/title order in the ToC using svmult.cls

Tags: table-of-contents, sv-classes

I am preparing the book of abstracts for a forthcoming conference using the useful Springer's `svmult` document class. However, using the standard `\tableofcontents` command gives a table of contents with the title of the contribution first and in boldface and the author's name below in normal font, like this:

[image: Example of TOC with Svmult]

I would need to reverse the order of title and author in the ToC, so that I have the author first (in boldface) and the contribution's title below and in normal font or italics. I tried to modify the `svmult.cls` file to do this, but I only managed to change the fonts and not the order of the entries. Any help with this would be hugely appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[graybox, openany]{svmult}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[authordate,natbib]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{helvet}         % selects Helvetica as sans-serif font
%\usepackage{courier}        % selects Courier as typewriter font
\usepackage{type1cm}        % activate if the above 3 fonts are
                         % not available on your system

\usepackage{makeidx}         % allows index generation
\usepackage{graphicx}        % standard LaTeX graphics tool
%                             % when including figure files
\usepackage{multicol}        % used for the two-column index
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom
%
%% see the list of further useful packages
%% in the Reference Guide
%
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\makeindex             % used for the subject index
%                       % please use the style svind.ist with
%                       % your makeindex program
%

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pifont}


%\usepackage{pst-text}

%%%% Additional font macros
\makeatletter
%%%% light series
%% e.g., s:12
\DeclareRobustCommand\ltseries
{\not@math@alphabet\ltseries\relax
   \fontseries\ltdefault\selectfont}
%% e.g., t:32
\newcommand{\ltdefault}{l}
%% e.g., v:19
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textlt}{\ltseries}

% heavy(bold) series
\DeclareRobustCommand\hbseries
  {\not@math@alphabet\hbseries\relax
\fontseries\hbdefault\selectfont}
%% e.g., t:32
\newcommand{\hbdefault}{hb} 
%% e.g., v:19
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\texthb}{\hbseries}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\isbn}{{\small\textsc{ISBN}}}

%%% for the Web-O-Mints fonts
\newcommand*{\wb}[2]{\fontsize{#1}{#2}\usefont{U}{webo}{xl}{n}}
%%% for the Fontsite 500 fonts
\newcommand*{\FSfont}[1]{%
\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{#1}\selectfont}
%\renewcommand*{\FSfont}[1]{}%    kills special font selections

\newcommand*{\labelit}[1]{\phantomsection\label{#1}}
\newcommand*{\refit}[1]{(graphic on page~\pageref{#1})}


\DeclareRobustCommand{\cs}[1]{\texttt{\char`\\#1}}
\newlength{\tpheight}\setlength{\tpheight}{0.9\textheight}
\newlength{\txtheight}\setlength{\txtheight}{0.9\tpheight}
\newlength{\tpwidth}\setlength{\tpwidth}{0.9\textwidth}
\newlength{\txtwidth}\setlength{\txtwidth}{0.9\tpwidth}
\newlength{\drop}

\newenvironment{showtitle}{%
\begin{boxminipage}[c][\tpheight]{\tpwidth}
\centering\begin{vplace}\begin{minipage}[c][\txtheight]{\txtwidth}}%
{\end{minipage}\end{vplace}\end{boxminipage}}



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

%List of contributors
\contributors
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Contributors}
\begin{thecontriblist}
John Smith
\at Fun University, USA, \email{john.smith@fun.edu}
\and
Brad Pitt
\at University of Fun, Canada, \email{bpitt@ufun.ca}
\end{thecontriblist}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Contribution 1

\author{John Smith}
\title*{Contribution 1}
% Use \titlerunning{Short Title} for an abbreviated version of
% your contribution title if the original one is too long
% Use \authorrunning{Short Title} for an abbreviated version of
% your contribution title if the original one is too long
\institute{John Smith
\at Fun University, USA, \email{john.smith@fun.edu}}
%\and Name of Second Author \at Name, Address of Institute      \email{name@email.address}}
%
% Use the package "url.sty" to avoid
% problems with special characters
% used in your e-mail or web address
\maketitle
\dominitoc 
\begin{refsection}
\abstract{\lipsum
\keywords{fun, funny}
}
%\section*{References}
%\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{refsection}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Contribution 2

\author{Brad Pitt}
\title*{Contribution 2}
\institute{Brad Pitt
\at University of Fun, Canada, \email{bpitt@ufun.ca}}
\maketitle
\dominitoc 
\begin{refsection}
\abstract{\lipsum
\keywords{lorem, ipsum}
}
%\section*{References}
%\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{refsection}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

The `svmult` document class can be downloaded at [the official Springer FTP repository](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/) (I think the newest version is the one in `/pub/tex/latex/svmultt1/`).

Comment: Welcome! A minimal document we can use to reproduce would be helpful. Even more important, where can we get the class? It is not in TeX Live, at least.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your reply! I have edited my questions with the information you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example (and I've minimized it quite a bit), you can swap around the placement of the title and author using a couple of [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) patches:

[image]

```
\documentclass{svmult}% ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/svmultt1/styles/svmult.cls

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{type1cm} % activate if the above 3 fonts are
                     % not available on your system

\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
% Remove printing of title and store it
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\if@numart\if}{\iffalse\if}{}{}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\else\if}{\fi\let\title@store\@title\iffalse\if}{}{}
% Update printing of author and insert title after
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\addcontentsline{toc}{author}{\toc@uthor}}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{title}{\toc@uthor}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{author}{\title@store}%
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

%List of contributors
\contributors
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Contributors}
\begin{thecontriblist}
John Smith
\at Fun University, USA, \email{john.smith@fun.edu}
\and
Brad Pitt
\at University of Fun, Canada, \email{bpitt@ufun.ca}
\end{thecontriblist}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Contribution 1

\author{John Smith}
\title*{Contribution 1}
\institute{John Smith
\at Fun University, USA, \email{john.smith@fun.edu}}
\maketitle

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Contribution 2

\author{Brad Pitt}
\title*{Contribution 2}
\institute{Brad Pitt
\at University of Fun, Canada, \email{bpitt@ufun.ca}}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

The idea is to replace the insertion of `\@title` in the ToC with that of `\toc@uthor` and *vice versa*. Some housekeeping is needed to store the title for use later.